# React.js Iterating through the index linearly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make changes on my project but I am kind of stuck with iteration on grabbing the data. I have Image.js file that contains this code below,

```
export const target_images = [
  {index: 0, category: 'target', 'image': require("C:\\Users\\kiddi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Code\\behavirol_project\\src\\assets\\1\\T1_01.jpg")},
  {'index': 1, 'category': 'target', 'image': require("C:\\Users\\kiddi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Code\\behavirol_project\\src\\assets\\2\\T2_01.jpg")},
  ...
]
export const non_target_images = [
  {index: 0, category: 'non-target', image: require("C:\\Users\\kiddi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Code\\behavirol_project\\src\\assets\\1\\C1_01.jpg")},
  {'index': 1, 'category': 'non-target', 'image': require("C:\\Users\\kiddi\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Code\\behavirol_project\\src\\assets\\1\\C1_02.jpg")},
 ...
```

and currently has program that will grabs the any index of the photo randomly from target_images and non_target_images. The purpose of this project is to display 3 rounds of 3x3 grids of image to the user containing 8 non_target photo and one target photo.

```
import React from "react";
import { target_images, non_target_images } from "../components/Image";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addData } from "../slices/ExcelSlice";

const ThreegridPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [imagesState, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [trialNumber, setTrialNumber] = useState(1);
  const [targetIndex, setTargetIndex] = useState();
  const [selectedImagesArray, setSelectedImagesArray] = useState([]);
  const [attempts, setAttempts] = useState(1);
  let start = new Date().getTime();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscribe = async () => {
      let images = [];
      let targetIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); // randomly select the index of the target image
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let image;
        if (i === targetIndex) { // set the target image at the randomly selected index
          image = target_images[Math.floor(Math.random() * target_images.length)];
        } else {
          image = non_target_images[Math.floor(Math.random() * non_target_images.length)];
        }
        images.push(image);
      }
      return images;
    };
    
    
    subscribe().then((images) => {
      shuffleArray(images).then((shuffledImages) => {
        setImages(shuffledImages); // final array
      });
    });
  }, []);
  
  function handleClickImage(image) {
    if (image?.category === "non-target") {
      setAttempts(attempts + 1);
      setSelectedImagesArray((selectedImagesArray) => [      ...selectedImagesArray,      image?.index,    ]);
    } else if (image?.category === "target") {
      setSelectedImagesArray([]);
      const end = new Date().getTime();
      const TimeTaken = end - start;
      start = 0;
      const subscribe = async (array) => {
        console.log("Array before", array);
        let newArray = array.slice(); // make a copy of the array
        let indexForTarget = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        newArray[targetIndex] = target_images[indexForTarget];
        return newArray;
      };
      setAttempts(attempts + 1);
      dispatch(
        addData({
          trial: trialNumber,
          attempts: attempts,
          time: TimeTaken / 100,
        })
      );
      if (trialNumber === 3) {
        subscribe(imagesState).then((newArray) => {
          shuffleArray(newArray).then((shuffledArray) => {
            console.log("Array after", shuffledArray);
            setImages(shuffledArray);
          });
        });
        navigate(`/6x6grid`);
      } else {
        subscribe(imagesState).then((newArray) => {
          shuffleArray(newArray).then((shuffledArray) => {
            shuffledArray.map((d, k) => {
              if (d?.category === "target") {
                setTargetIndex(k);
              }
            });
            setImages(shuffledArray);
          });
        });
        setAttempts(1);
        setTrialNumber(trialNumber + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  async function shuffleArray(array) {
    let shuffledArray = array.slice(); // make a copy of the array
    for (let i = shuffledArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
      const temp = shuffledArray[i];
      shuffledArray[i] = shuffledArray[j];
      shuffledArray[j] = temp;
    }
    return shuffledArray;
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="headerText">Practice Trial 3x3 Grid</div>
      <div className="image-grid">
        {imagesState.length &&
          imagesState.map((image, key) => {
            return (
              <div
                className="grid-item"
                key={key}
                onClick={() => handleClickImage(image)}
              >
                <img
                  src={image?.image}
                  width="120px"
                  height="120px"
                  alt={image?.index}
                  style={{
                    opacity:
                      selectedImagesArray.includes(image?.index) &&
                      image?.category === "non-target"
                        ? 0
                        : 1,
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ThreegridPage;
```

I've try to use counter but I'm not sure have to start the next round of photo with previous counter.
For example in:
1st round, it should be ( target_image: index 0 and non_target_image will be index 0 through 7)
second round will be ( target_image: index 1 and non_target_image will be index 8 through 16)
third round will be (target_image: index 2 and non_target_image will be index 16-24)

Comment: Since it has been 4 hours and no one has provided any feedback, I would suggest you update your question to include a link to a CodePen that demonstrates the issue you are having, and possibly an image or mockup that shows your desired end product.  I suggest this because as I read through your question, I really am not following the behavior you are describing, nor do I understand what you are trying to create.  And since you have dependencies on local code (`../slices/ExcelSlice`) that is not included in your snippet, I already know that if I try to run your code, I am just gonna get errors.

Comment: My code doesn't have any error and works completely fine

Comment: Great to hear!  So why are you here on StackOverflow?